# Laravel keyby by Date

Tags: laravel

Trying to use keyby, for managing key-value problems.

```
$result = Calendar::select(array(
            '*',
            DB::raw('DATE(`start_at`) as `x`')
          ))->where('user_id', 2)->with('project')->get()->keyBy('x');
```

start_at field format is: 2020-04-14 20:00:00

My expectation was the response like:

```
"2020-04-08":{
     [
       {
        "id":1,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
        },
       {
        "id":4,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
        },
       {
        "id":5,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
        },
     ]
   },
   "2020-04-13":{
     [
       {
        "id":2,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
        },
       {
        "id":3,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
        },
     ]
   },
```

But it returns like:

```
"2020-04-08":{
        "id":5,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
   },
   "2020-04-13":{
        "id":2,
        "my_data": "blablabala"
   },
```

In short; It returned one record per day. It didn't make 'keyby' functionality like expected.
What's wrong with it?

Comment: that is what keying by something would do ... sounds like you are looking to "group" things together

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `groupBy` on the collection instead of `keyBy` to achieve the result you desire.

What keyBy does is assign the provided column as the index/key for the array, where as `groupBy` will group the matching records together.

```
$result = Calendar::select(array('*', DB::raw('DATE(`start_at`) as `x`')))
    ->where('user_id', 2)
    ->with('project')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('x');
```

You can also pass a function to groupBy and let Carbon do the formatting/processing for you.

```
$result = Calendar::where('user_id', 2)
    ->with('project')
    ->get()
    ->groupBy(function ($record) {
        return Carbon::parse($record->start_at)->format('Y-m-d');
    });
```